# how to get salesforce credentials in php application

Tags: php, salesforce

I have integrated a PHP application into salesfoce.To do that ,I have created a 'web tab' in salesforce and added my local URL.When I click on the tab, my PHP application opens inside the salesfoce.

Now what I need is, I want to get the salesfoce credentials(username,password and security token) into my php file to get authorised.Currently it is hardcoded.

Please advice me a simple method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the SFDC oauth docs?
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US